# Maintain container scroll position when resizing with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a container with overflow;scroll defined on a web page. This container will resize periodically based on a variable, for example it may change from 1 to 2, which causes the width of the container to double.

This is for a dynamic timeline.

I will have access to both the old and new value, and will need to maintain the same scroll position (ie, the date the user is looking at).

I've attempted this, but it doesn't quite work:

```
            var container = $("#container");
            var difference = newValue / oldValue;
            var newScrollPixels = container.scrollLeft() * difference;
            container.scrollLeft(newScrollPixels);
```

Is there something I'm missing here?

Please not this code fires after the resizing has taken place.

Comment: can you float the date div to left and say margin-left:30px; would that help?

Comment: huh? I'm not sure if I follow you.. I want to maintain the same relative scroll position (as a percentage)

Comment: You should put a example at jsfiddle.net otherwise its difficult to understand. May be on a button click you can change the content in the example. Without a example nobody would get your problem.

Comment: It's pretty simple. If the container was 1000px wide, and the scroll was at 50%. Then if the container resized to 1500px then the scroll needs to be readjusted so it's still at 50%.

Comment: Thats what I m not getting and never will if you do not show a example. In the css if you say scroll's width to be 50% then it should remain so if the container's width changes.